# How to make part of application always visible

Tags: java, android

I want to display part of my application foreground view always on top when device is in active state.

Is it possible to present some data always on top of android screen event if another application is in foreground mode or home screen is active?

Please take a look at the pictures below:
[image]

Is it possible to make application behavior similar to navigation bar? - [picture](http://img.wonderhowto.com/img/47/94/63539481532791/0/get-android-ls-navigation-bar-your-nexus-running-4-0.1280x600.jpg).

I couldn't find a similar solution and also there is nothing about it in android docs.

Comment: I can tell you it's possible, "CamSam Plus" use this kind of feature, but I can't tell you how.

Comment: It's possible with a screen overlay if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: After quick search for 'android screen overlay', google  results says this is rather problem than feature... . Everything is about turning it off than implementing. Can you publish more information about this mechanism?